# How do I draw a picturebox at run time?

Tags: c#, picturebox, redraw

```
 public void read_file(string fname)
    {
        filepath = fname;

        TextReader input = File.OpenText(filepath);
        line = input.ReadLine();
        int[] ID = new int[6];
        int[] x = new int[6];
        int[] y = new int[6];
        int xx, yy;
        int i = 0;
        image = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(filename);
        smal1 = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(smallimg1);
        smal2 = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(smallimg2);
        smal3 = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(smallimg3);
        smal4 = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(smallimg4);
        smal5 = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(smallimg5);
        smal6 = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(smallimg6);


        //  int index = 0;
        while (line != null && line != " ")
        {


            if (line == "change")
            {
                while (line != "end")
                {

                    line = input.ReadLine();
                    line = line.Trim();
                    if (line != "end")
                    {
                        string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        xx = int.Parse(parts[0]);
                        yy = int.Parse(parts[1]);
                        image.SetPixel(xx, yy, Color.Blue);
                    }

                }
                line = input.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                string[] parts2 = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                ID[i] = int.Parse(parts2[0]);
                x[i] = int.Parse(parts2[1]);
                y[i] = int.Parse(parts2[2]);
                line = input.ReadLine();
                if(ID[i]==1)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Size = smal1.Size;
                    pictureBox2.Image = smal1;
                }
                else if (ID[i] == 2)
                {
                    pictureBox3.Size = smal2.Size;
                    pictureBox3.Image = smal2;
                }
                else if (ID[i] == 3)
                {
                    pictureBox4.Size = smal3.Size;
                    pictureBox4.Image = smal3;
                }
                else if (ID[i] == 4)
                {
                    pictureBox5.Size = smal4.Size;
                    pictureBox5.Image = smal4;
                }
                else if (ID[i] == 5)
                {
                    pictureBox6.Size = smal5.Size;
                    pictureBox6.Image = smal5;
                }
                else if (ID[i] == 6)
                {
                    pictureBox7.Size = smal6.Size;
                    pictureBox7.Image = smal6;
                }
                    i++;
            }
        }
       // pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
       // pictureBox2.Image = smal;
       // pictureBox2.Size = smal.Size;
        pictureBox1.Image = image;
        pictureBox1.Size = image.Size;
        //pictureBox2.Hide();
    }

    public Form1()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        capture_flag = true;
        start_reading();

    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        capture_flag = false;
    }

    private void start_reading()
    {

        string filen = "F:/4th year/1st Term/sensor network/proj/reconstructscene/stream.txt";
        read_file(filen);
        filen = "F:/4th year/1st Term/sensor network/proj/reconstructscene/stream1.txt";
        read_file(filen);
        filen = "F:/4th year/1st Term/sensor network/proj/reconstructscene/stream2.txt";
        read_file(filen);

    }

    private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

in the above code i'm trying to call the function read_file several times but it's not working 
the form just wait until the end then draw once .

note in the original project i'll take the file name from another part of the poject and i may call the function like

```
while (capture_flag)
        {

        filen = file;
        read_file(filen);
        }
```

which not working for the same reason

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the changes doesn't show up whlie the method is running, is that the main thread is busy running the method so it's not listening to messages. The updates happens in the form of messages that are placed on the message queue, so when the main thread can't handle the messages, there are no updates.

You can use the `Refresh` method to force a redraw of the control while in the middle of the method:

```
pictureBox2.Size = smal1.Size;
pictureBox2.Image = smal1;
pictureBox2.Refresh();
```

Comment: but there is a new problem which is while i'm drawing i cannot use any button i should stop the program from the vs it self, any suggestions?

Comment: @Emykindman: Same there, button events are handled using messages. You can issue calls to `Environment.DoEvents` at regular intervals in the method to make it handle messages, but that is a bit of a kludge. You should consider running the method in a background thread, so that the main thread is free to handle messages.